# Django template loop missing <form> element on first iteration

Tags: django, dom

I've got a really weird error, and I don't know whether it's the django template error or something weird happening in the DOM.

I have a list of dictionaries called `data_table`, which I pass as part of the context to the template engine. I'm trying to create rows in a table, and one of the cells is this:

```
{% for row in data_table %}
<tr>
    <!-- a few cells ... followed by the final cell which contains a form -->
    <td>
    <form action="/remove-survey-question/" method="POST">
        <a href="#" onclick="removeSurveyQuestion(this)">
            <image class="trash-svg" src="{% static "trash.svg" %}">
        </a>
        <input type="hidden" name="question_type" value="{{ row.question_type }}" />
        <!-- some more hidden inputs... -->
    </form>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This works perfectly *except* for the first row. The javascript function throws an error because, when I use the browser's DOM inspector, the parent `<form>` node is missing! All the child nodes of the missing `<form>` are present though.

How could this happen? I'm using django 1.9.2.

Comment: To iterate over dictionary should not it be `{% for row in data_table.values %}` or `{% for key, value in data_table.iteritems %}`. Tag `image` looks wrong, should be `img`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant "list of dictionaries". I've edited. You're right about the <img> tag too, I was absent-minded when copy-pasting and trying to remove the irrelevant code. Also, I think in python3 (what I'm using) it's {% dictionary.items %} to iterate.

Comment: There isn't any issues with the code you've shown here? what is the actual error message you get?..

Comment: Don't see other problems, maybe something wrong in the cells before, some unclosed tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just compared the source vs the DOM, and the `<form>` tag is present in the source, but not the DOM. The reason was that I had inadvertently created a nested form (which is not allowed).